# Maven build failure with Rule violated error for junit test class

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, junit, sonarqube

Find below points,

- cannot find jacoco plugin anywhere in the project.
- tried configuring jacoco in pom.xml file,but it didn't worked.
- if I add <jacoco.skip>true</jacoco.skip> in properties then maven build is success but sonar coverage shows 0%.

Getting below error for the classes for which junit test cases written.

```
[WARNING] Rule violated for class  dbadapter.persistence.serviceimpl.ExcepListPersistenceService: lines covered ratio is 0.40, but expected minimum is 0.80
[WARNING] Rule violated for class  dbadapter.persistence.serviceimpl.SearchPersistenceService: branches covered ratio is 0.50, but expected minimum is 0.80
[WARNING] Rule violated for class  dbadapter.persistence.serviceimpl.UpdatePersistenceService: lines covered ratio is 0.45, but expected minimum is 0.80
[WARNING] Rule violated for class  dbadapter.persistence.serviceimpl.UpdatePersistenceService: branches covered ratio is 0.50, but expected minimum is 0.80
[WARNING] Rule violated for class  dbadapter.persistence.serviceimpl.RePersistenceService: branches covered ratio is 0.50, but expected minimum is 0.80
[WARNING] Rule violated for class  dbadapter.persistence.serviceimpl.TypeRefPersistenceService: lines covered ratio is 0.00, but expected minimum is 0.80
[WARNING] Rule violated for class  dbadapter.persistence.serviceimpl.TSOPersistenceService: lines covered ratio is 0.40, but expected minimum is 0.80
[WARNING] Rule violated for class  dbadapter.persistence.serviceimpl.ImportDatePersistenceService: lines covered ratio is 0.28, but expected minimum is 0.80
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for dataaccess-parent 1.0.0.4-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] dataaccess-parent .................................. SUCCESS [ 10.547 s]
[INFO] dataaccess-api ..................................... SUCCESS [ 20.339 s]
[INFO] dataaccess-model ................................... SUCCESS [ 11.127 s]
[INFO] dataaccess-foundation .............................. SUCCESS [ 11.869 s]
[INFO] dataaccess-dbadapter ............................... FAILURE [ 13.428 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.1:check (check) on project dataaccess-dbadapter: Coverage checks have not been met. See log for details. -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: parent pom may be?

Comment: If you don't know where that comes from, someone on your project presumably set that up right? Why don't you just improve the coverage rather than try to disable the checks?

Comment: `0.8` is the default setting! [see here](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/check-mojo.html)

Comment: Junit has been written for every single line of from classes, still getting rule violated.